# ESP8266 Restarts When A Motor Is In Use

Tags: power-supply, motor, dc-motor, esp8266

So I'm working on my Senior Design Project currently. We are building a circuit with the ESP8266 Microcontroller that is connected with a Motor Driver to control a motor. The issue that we are facing is that whenever the motor is in use, it will eventually force the microcontroller to reset. Whether if it's on once for 1 second, or five times for 3 seconds, the microcontroller eventually resets.

We have tried adding a inductor in series with the motor to limit the start up current and tried adding a capacitor to the input voltage of the ESP8266, but no success. The only potential issue I can think of is our test set up. We have our setup soldered onto a perfboard. I feel like there may be electromagnetic interferance with all of the wires overlapping with eachother, but I don't know for sure. If that is the case, then it may be better to get a 2 layer PCB. [image: Schematic]

The motor driver we are using is the TB6612FNG and we are using the breakout variant on Sparkfuns website. Our 5V power source is coming from a wall outlet USB charger. And for the +VM voltage, we are using a 7.4V Lithium Ion Battery Pack. Any advice to help us solve this issue would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Brownouts are not uncommon, but you don't show how the various supplies relate.

Comment: We were going to do some testing tomorrow morning. We planned on using a scope to read the input voltage on the micro to see when we are getting a brownout.

Comment: Does this occur when powered by the battery, the external 5V supply or both?

Comment: The reset on the ESP8266 is floating. Try tieing it to the correct potential (I think it is 3.3V but it maybe GND, so check the datasheet) and check what happens.

Comment: Brownout is a possible cause, a programming mistake another one. Query the reset reason at the start of your program to determine which one it is (search for `getResetInfoPtr`).

Comment: Completely agree with Huisman, your reset is floating. I learned this when my microcontroller reset with 50Hz, because of the line frequency.

Comment: I tried out your suggestion Huisman, and still no luck. I think that the reset is already tied high since I am using a development board.

It occurs in both cases jramsay42.